# How to change MainActivity's variable with AlertDialog Android

Tags: android

Good morning everybody,

I have encountered some problems with AlertDialog. I have an EditText component, and I would like to get the text entered in a MainActivity's variable.

Here is my code :

```
private void showDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.enter_comment);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// name is the variable I want to change. It has been declared as String name; at the beginning of my MainActivity class.
            name = input.getText().toString();
            showToast(name);
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.annuler, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            builder.show();
        }
    });
// This line makes the app crash. It doesn't print "Null String" as it should.
    //showToast(name);
}

private void showToast(String str) {
    if (str != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I hope you'll be able to help me.
Thank you in advance !

**EDIT - Added full code** (except the imports -> too many)

```
package com.example.ghost.boxmonitor;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.ghost.boxmonitor.USB_PERMISSION";
    Button startButton, clearButton, stopButton;
    TextView textView;
    UsbManager usbManager;
    UsbDevice device;
    UsbSerialDevice serialPort;
    UsbDeviceConnection connection;
    LinkedList<Box> list;
    String text,name;

UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
    @Override
    public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
            data.concat("/n");
            tvAppend(textView, data);
            buildString(data);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
};
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { //Broadcast Receiver to automatically start and stop the Serial connection.
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
            boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            if (granted) {
                connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
                if (serialPort != null) {
                    if (serialPort.open()) { //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
                        setUiEnabled(true);
                        serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
                        serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                        serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                        serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                        serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                        serialPort.read(mCallback);
                        tvAppend(textView,"Serial Connection Opened!\n");

                    } else {
                        tvAppend(textView,"Port not opened\n");
                        Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT NOT OPEN");
                    }
                } else {
                    tvAppend(textView,"Port null\n");
                    Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT IS NULL");
                }
            } else {
                tvAppend(textView,"Perm not granted\n");
                Log.d("SERIAL", "PERM NOT GRANTED");
            }
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
            onClickStart(startButton);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
            onClickStop(stopButton);
        }
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(this.USB_SERVICE);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    setUiEnabled(false);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    list = new LinkedList<Box>();

}

public void setUiEnabled(boolean bool) {
    startButton.setEnabled(!bool);
    stopButton.setEnabled(bool);
    textView.setEnabled(bool);

}

public void onClickStart(View view) {

    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
    if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
        boolean keep = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
            device = entry.getValue();
            int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
            tvAppend(textView, "Device VID : "+Integer.toString(deviceVID)+"\n");
            if (deviceVID == 10755 || deviceVID == 9025)//Arduino Vendor ID
            {
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                tvAppend(textView,"Arduino detected. Waiting for user authorization...\n");
                usbManager.requestPermission(device, pi);
                keep = false;
            } else {
                connection = null;
                device = null;
                tvAppend(textView,"This device is not an Arduino.\n");
            }

            if (!keep)
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        tvAppend(textView,"No USB device detected.\n");
    }


}

public void onClickStop(View view) {
    setUiEnabled(false);
    serialPort.close();
    tvAppend(textView, "\nUSB device unplugged.\nSerial Connection Closed !\n");

}

public void onClickClear(View view) {
    textView.setText(" ");
    showDialog();
}

private void tvAppend(TextView tv, CharSequence text) {
    final TextView ftv = tv;
    final CharSequence ftext = text;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ftv.append(ftext);
        }
    });
}

public void interpreter(String text){
    String table[] = text.split("&");
    String def = Integer.toString(list.size() + 1);
    if (table.length == 2) {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            //showDialog();
            Box b = new Box(table[0], table[1], def);
            list.add(b);
            //tvAppend(textView2, b.execute());
        } else {
            boolean isInList = false;
            for (Box b : list) {
                if (b.getAddr().compareTo(table[0]) == 0) {
                    isInList = true;
                    b.setState(table[1]);
                    //tvAppend(textView2, b.execute());
                }
            }
            if (!isInList) {
                //showDialog();
                Box b = new Box(table[0], table[1], def);
                list.add(b);
                //tvAppend(textView2, b.execute());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void buildString(String data){
    int len = data.length();
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++){
        c = data.charAt(i);
        switch (c){
            case '#':
                text = "";
                break;
            case '!':
                interpreter(text);
                break;
            default:
                text+=c;
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void showDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                name = input.getText().toString();
                Log.d("MyTag", "name in onClick()" + name);
                showToast(name);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();
        showToast(name);
    }


private void showToast(String str) {
    if (str != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

So each time I receive data on the serial line, I build a string, and if the string is complete, I call the interpreter. If the string describes a new Box, I call the showDialog method to ask the user to give it a name.

**EDIT EDIT - Solution**

Please see the answer below, and the related comments. As far as I understood the problem,  you can't change the UI inside another thread than the UiThread (it seems obvious now, but ...).

Comment: What u mean by 'I would like to get the text entered in a MainActivity's variable' ? actually what u need to achieve ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like to get the text written by the user in the EditText component and write it into the name variable, to use it in others functions.

Comment: Which is the edittext that you want to get text from ?

Comment: The one named input.

Comment: Okey, i think the edit text named input is inside the layout file for MainActivity.Use findViewById() to get access to the edit text and get text from that using input.gettext().toString().
add this line in onCreate of MainActivity 
input = findViewById(R.id.edittext_input);

Comment: Actually, input is created dynamically, and I can't access its enclosed text with this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying honestly, I also didn't got your issue.
This line in your code `name = input.getText().toString();` do assignment to a `name` variable.
Check it with logs - put

```
name = input.getText().toString();
Log.d("MyTag", "name in onClick()" + name);
```

Then in console I saw:
[image]

So it's working. After `dialog` was dismissed, you can use your `name` variable.
Or please specify more details.

**PS. One tip.** If you use your `showDialog()` method in your `Activity`, there is no need to use `runOnUiThread` trick. Just call `builder.show();`, it works.

**Ok, here is complete code of `Activity`**, everything is working, including Toast in the end of `showDialog()` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String ACTION = "myActionForBroadcast";
    String name;

    private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("MyTag", "onReceive: context" + context.getPackageCodePath());
            showDialog();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MyTag", "Handler run: before send broadcast");
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(ACTION));
            }
        }, 5_000);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("MyTag", "showDialog onClick: name before assign " + name);
                name = input.getText().toString();
                Log.d("MyTag", "showDialog onClick: name after assign " + name);
                showToast(name);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        Log.d("MyTag", "showDialog: before showing dialog");
        builder.show();
        Log.d("MyTag", "showDialog: before showing toast");
        showToast(name);
    }

    private void showToast(String str) {
        if (str != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Null String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

I've changed code of `Activity`. Here is what have been done:
1) I declared `receiver` with some custom action;
2) I emulated `onReceive()` 5 seconds after start;
3) in `onReceive()` I just showed dialog:
4) put logs on events.

Everything is working, see the output in console.
[image]

What I can propose you - in your `onReceive()` just call the `showDialog()` and see, if it works.
If yes - then something wrong is in your that code.

**!!** Also, if you register receiver in onCreate(), don't forget to unregister it in onDestroy()!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I do agree with you, it should work. However it just doesn't. And I can't check the assignment with log as this dialog appears when the phone receive something via its UsbSerialInterface. So I have to test directly on the phone, and to check if the variable has been assigned, I use Toasts. If I call the showToast method just after the assignment, it works, but, when I call it at the end of the showDialog method, it doesn't. The app crashes.

Comment: Please check updated answer, I provide full Activity code, everything is fine.

Comment: Also, pls provide stackTrace of exception. You can debug your app by calling showDialog() method not only when connecting via USB, but call it method in other place.

Comment: I tried your code, calling the showDialog method with a button, and indeed it worked, both on the phone and the emulator. However, when the method is called by the UsbSerialInterface, I mean when I receive a type of serial data, the app crashes.

Comment: Indeed everything is working. I may have found another solution. I think that as I was calling the show dialog() method inside a sort of thread (the serial callback function ) I couldn't change the UI. By calling this method inside runOnUiThread, it also solved the problem. Anyway, thanks for your answer !